# How to add css pseudo element in react

Tags: css, reactjs

How do I add CSS pseudo-element `::after` dynamically through react. I have a header where I'm setting its background color to black on scroll. Now I want to add `::after` as well on scroll where I could add some more styling to it. Is there any way I could achieve this?

```
const Header = () => {

  const [ headerColor, setHeaderColor ] = useState(false);

  const headerColorChange = () => {
    window.scrollY >= 80 ? setHeaderColor(true) : setHeaderColor(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", headerColorChange)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <header id="header" className={ headerColor ? 'header-color' : null}>
        
    </header>
  )
}
```

In my CSS file:

```
.header-color {
    background-color: $black;
}
```

I would like to add `::after` to my header so that I could add more styling to it. (on Scroll)

```
&::after {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Before scroll my `::after` is at `#header`

```
#header::after {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $white;
  }
```

Comment: Just add the CSS you want. e.g. .header-color::after{ max-width: 100%;}

Comment: @AHaworth, that's exactly what I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: @AHaworth I think its because my `::after` before the scroll is on `#header`

Comment: `#header` has higher specificity than `.header-color`. Try nesting them, so that the selector will be `#header.header-color`.

Comment: @yainspan thank you. It worked. If you want to write your comment as an answer. I will accept it.